# Qt WindowMaximize not changing geometry (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, geometry, window-resize, qmainwindow

So I'm making a web browser as my first Qt project (surprise!) and I'm wondering why calling `setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized)` is not changing window geometry. I have this code:

From mainwindow.h:

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

From mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // this->geometry() is the same here...
    setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    ui->webView->setGeometry(0, 60, geometry().width(), geometry().height()-60);
    // ...as it is here.
}
```

As you may be able to tell, I'm trying to start the application with the window maximized and the QWebView also maximized. Basically, whenever the main window is resized, I also want to call `ui->webView->setGeometry` with the update height and width. But `MainWindow::geometry` doesn't seem to be updating. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to double check, but your geometry might not get updated properly until your main window gets a show event.

However, I would suggest you put your QWebView inside of a layout instead of trying to size it manually every time your main window changes size.

Comment: OK, would a grid layout make the most sense in this case?

Comment: You should be fine with a QBoxLayout or QStackedLayout. The 60 pixels margin can be set with the parent widget's setContentsMargins() function.